# Can't connect to any SQL instances with latest EntityFramework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4.1, connection-string, ef-code-first

I've just updated my EntityFramework from
EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0
to
EntityFramework.4.1.10715.0

With this version I can't connect to a single database instance on my local machine or a variety of remote machines, using either integrated security or SQL based authentication.

Connections still work fine if I use the the old 4.1.10331.0 release.

The specific error I get is below, however the instances I'm connecting to are all default instances.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

My SQL based authentication connection string looks as follows

> Server=localhost;Database=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password;

Has anyone else ran across this or can anyone suggest possible causes?

Comment: you are missing a `;` between username and password. try `Server=localhost;Database=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password;`

Comment: Thank Eranga, that a was a typo from removing my credentials but I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working however I'm still not totally sure what the reasoning behind it is. I think it may perhaps be related to a Provider configuration as suggested by Yuck.

Against the 4.1.10331.0 build I was setting the connectionstring on the DBContext as follows and it worked fine.

```
Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password;"
```

However, against build 4.1.10715.0 this would result in the error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified exception.

I now pass the connectionstring into the constructor of my context, which in turn passed that onto its base constructor. Everything then works fine as expected.

```
public TestContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) {}

...

var context = new TestContext("Server=localhost;Database=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password;")
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your connection string has the `provider` attribute specified:

```
SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dbname;USER ID=username;
PASSWORD=password;PROVIDER=System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: I tried adding the provider value to my connectionstring but I got the error - Keyword not supported: 'provider'.

Comment: @WDuffy How about `providerName`?